# React : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'i' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I have a problem with my code:

```
class Albs extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      i: 0,
      anh: this.props.hinhanh[this.state.i]
    };
    var hinhanh = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"];
    this.state.i = this.state.i.bind(this);
  }
  nextPic(){
    this.setState({i: this.state.i++});
  }
  backPic(){
    this.setState({i: this.state.i--});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.anh}/>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={nextPic}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={backPic}>Back</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Albs/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In console it shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'i' of undefined. Reason please?

Comment: Remove `this.state.i = this.state.i.bind(this);`

Comment: In the line 
     ```this.state = {
         i: 0,
         anh: this.props.hinhanh[this.state.i]
      };``` it looks like you're trying to use ```this.state.i``` before it has been completely initialized. Try using 0 for the array index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the class `this` to your methods nextPic and backPic as you do with `this.state.i` (I don't see how it's necessary)

Or you could use this syntax

```js
nextPic = () => {
    this.setState({i: this.state.i++});
  }
  backPic = () => {
    this.setState({i: this.state.i--});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of mistakes you made, look at my code and compare yours. Hope you can find the error.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      i: 0
    };
    var hinhanh = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"];
    this.nextPic = this.nextPic.bind(this);
    this.backPic = this.backPic.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ anh: this.state.i});
  }

  nextPic() {
    this.setState({ i: this.state.i++ });
    console.log(this.state.i);
  }
  backPic() {
    this.setState({ i: this.state.i-- });
    console.log(this.state.i);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.anh}/>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.nextPic}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={this.backPic}>Back</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

- You can define state property immediately into state like this `this.state = { i: 0, j: this.state.i}, here`j`is undefined. So you need to use life cycle method`componentDidMount`to`setState`.
- You need to bind your functions, otherwise you need to use arrow function like this, `nextPic = () => {//function defination}`